# I need help createing a priority queue in c++

Tags: c++, templates, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to create a priority queue program that has a string as its data and the number as the priority level in, enqueue("Hello", 3);
Below is what I have thus far but I am having a hard time putting everything together, any help on what I should be doing differently or helping me to write the program would be greatly appreciated.

I believe I should store the queue in a vector and somehow sort the data inside to match the corresponding priority level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <class T1, class T2>
class PriQueue
{
public:
//PriQueue();
void enqueue(T1 str, T2 pri); //Adds to queue
void dequeue(T1 str, T2 pri); //Deletes from queue
void peek(T1 str, T2 pri); //Prints the the first in queue
void size(T1 size); //Prints how many in queue

T1 printQ();

private:
T1 s;
T2 p;

};

template <class T1, class T2>
void PriQueue<T1, T2>::enqueue(T1 str, T2 pri) //Adding an element to the queue
{


this->s = str;
this->p = pri;

}

template <class T1, class T2>
void PriQueue<T1, T2>::dequeue(T1 str, T2 pri) //Removing an element from the front of the queue
{


}

template <class T1, class T2>
void PriQueue<T1, T2>::peek(T1 str, T2 pri) //Returning a value at front of the queue (NOT removing it)
{


}

template <class T1, class T2>
void PriQueue<T1, T2>::size(T1 size) //Returning the number of items in the queue.
{


}



using namespace std;


int main()
{

PriQueue<string, int> que;

que.enqueue("Hello", 3);
que.enqueue("Bye", 2);
que.enqueue("No", 5);

cout << que.printQ() << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at using the [``std::priority_queue``](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) with a custom ``comparitor`` and simply pass it ``std::pair<std::string, int>`` as the data type. Unless your assignment is to actually implement one from scratch, in which case I would highly recommend researching [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

Comment: There are too many gaps to be filled in your code. I just want to point out one thing that jumped out. The type of `pri` in all your function needs to be `int`, not `T`.

Comment: @RSahu Why is that? `pri` could also be a `double` and I don't see anything wrong with it being a template.

Comment: @nwp, the OP changed the question after I wrote the comment.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, sorry I have been making changes and edits as I change my code

Answer (score 2):

I would direct you to cppreference for std::priority_queue. That should help I think. As well as Priority Queue on wikipedia gives a nice segment on implementations.